# Find all lines in a text file that have at least two words in common (Bash)

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have several large text files produced by different people. These files contain listings of a single title per line. Every sentence is different, but supposedly refer to the same -unknown- set of items.

Given that formats and wording are different, I tried generating a shorter file with likely matches for manual inspection. I am new to Bash and I tried several commands to compare each line with titles having two or more key words in common. Case sensitive should be avoided and key words over 4 characters long to exclude articles and the like.

Example:

Input Text File #1

```
Investigating Amusing King : Expl and/in the Proletariat
Managing Self-Confident Legacy: The Harlem Renaissance and/in the Abject
Inventing Sarcastic Silence: The Harlem Renaissance and/in the Invader
Inventing Random Ethos: The Harlem Renaissance and/in the Marginalized
Loss: Supplementing Transgressive Production and Assimilation
```

Input Text File #2

```
Loss: Judging Foolhardy Historicism and Homosexuality
Loss: Developping Homophobic Textuality and Outrage
Loss: Supplement of transgressive production
Loss: Questioning Diligent Verbiage and Mythos
Me Against You: Transgressing Easygoing Materialism and Dialectic
```

Output Text File

```
File #1-->Loss: Supplementing Transgressive Production and Assimilation
File #2-->Loss: Supplement of transgressive production
```

So far I have been able to weed out a few duplicates with exact same entries...

```
cat FILE_num*.txt | sort | uniq -d > berbatim_duplicates.txt
```

...and a few other which had identical annotations between brackets

```
  cat FILE_num*.txt | sort | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1 | uniq -d > same_annotations.txt
```

A command that looks very promising is find with regex, but I am failing to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this problem is well suited to `bash` - certainly not a one-liner! Consider using a scripting language like Python, so you can more easily keep track of the lines in each of your files.

Comment: Ok, would you be so kind to provide me an example or some indication to get started. thx

Comment: There must be two common key words, but in your example "Supplement"=="Supplementing"

Comment: @Labo I think the common words are `Transgressive` and `Production`.

Comment: What if there is more than one line with the key words `Transgressive` and `Production` ?

Comment: @Labo In that case it'd be great if they are grouped so I can decide. I expect more problems to arise, but hopefully I can reduce the list enough to be manageable.

Comment: How big are your files ? (in lines)

Comment: @Labo over two thousand each file...

Comment: Is it possible for a line to be present in several bindings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 :

```
from sys import argv
from re import sub

def getWordSet(line):
    line=sub(r'\[.*\]|\(.*\)|[.,!?:]','',line).split()
    s=set()
    for word in line:
        if len(word)>4:
            word=word.lower()
            s.add(word)
    return s

def compare(file1, file2):
    file1 = file1.split('\n')
    file2 = file2.split('\n')
    for line1,set1 in zip(file1,map(getWordSet,file1)):
        for line2,set2 in zip(file2,map(getWordSet,file2)):
            if len(set1.intersection(set2))>1:
                print("File #1-->",line1,sep='')
                print("File #2-->",line2,sep='')

if __name__=='__main__':
    with open(argv[1]) as file1, open(argv[2]) as file2:
        compare(file1.read(),file2.read())
```

gives the expected output.
It displays the matching pairs of lines of the files.

Save this script in a file - I'll refer to it as script.py, but you can name it as you want. You can launch it with

```
python3 script.py file1 file2
```

You can even use an alias :

```
alias comp="python3 script.py"
```

and then

```
comp file1 file2
```

I included the features from the discussion below.

Comment: Thank you Labo, but gives me an error: File "find duplicates.py", line 16
    print("File #1-->",line1,sep='')
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ok, I have zero experience with Python so after investigating a bit I changed your prints with this print("File #1--> %s" % line1) and it worked just fine. Thank you!

Comment: It is because you used Python 2. If it is fine, I add command line support.

Comment: After some testing the only problem so far is that it should avoid any string between brackets now. So I'll try removing them from files using bash. Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of a string between brackets?

Comment: Yes, for example this one: The Industrial Organization of Markets with Two-Sided Platforms, 2005 (Evans and Schmalensee) [National Bureau of Economic Research, Inc.]

Comment: I am way too lazy to test my new code. Would you try it please ?
The fun fact is that I used regex this time ;)

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. Those lines with same strings between brackets are listed as matches although titles are completely different. For example, the following line is mistaken with the last example I gave you before: U.S. v. Microsoft: Did Consumers Win?, 2005 (Evans and Schmalensee) [National Bureau of Economic Research, Inc.]

Comment: There is some common "words" : 2005, Evans, Schmalensee. I may assume you want to remove the words in parenthesis as well. It is corrected.

Comment: Yes, only titles matter because there are plenty of titles from the same authors, editorial, etc

Comment: I should then remove ponctuation as well.

Comment: Now, the characters .,!?: are not anymore read. There should not be any false negative from now.

Comment: Now it totally rocks! thank you again. You've been very helpful and patient. If there is anything else I will figure it out myself.

Comment: You are welcome !
The best thing you can do is learning Python 3 :) It is a very powerful though simple language. You don't even need all the OOP part, just the basic syntax, the file opening and the string manipulation functions, and its power will be overwhelming !

Comment: I will definitely follow your advice. I studied c++, assembler and the like at the Uni ages ago...and Python seems powerful and pretty accessible at the same time. Bye!