# find and delete duplicate content in several files

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have **many files (acls)** containing ips, macs, hostnames and other data.

Important: The problem is about "duplicate content" in files. No "duplicate lines"

Example: (only a file, but i have several acls)

```
192.168.1.20;08:00:00:00:00:01;peter
192.168.1.21;08:00:00:00:00:01;android
192.168.1.21;08:00:00:00:00:02;john
192.168.1.22;08:00:00:00:00:03;julia
192.168.1.23;08:00:00:00:00:04;android
```

Lines with duplicate content. And this is what i want. A command to tell me this result:

```
192.168.1.20;08:00:00:00:00:01;peter
192.168.1.21;08:00:00:00:00:01;android
192.168.1.21;08:00:00:00:00:02;john
192.168.1.23;08:00:00:00:00:04;android
```

The duplicate content into a lines above is 08:00:00:00:00:01, 192.168.1.21 and android

Command I use to find duplicates into acls folder (doesn't work):

```
cat /home/user/files/* | sort | uniq -c | head -20
```

I've tried with this [python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594536/find-all-lines-in-a-text-file-that-have-at-least-two-words-in-common-bash), but the results are not as expected

First (At least) i want to detect the lines with duplicate content, and (if possible) delete lines with duplicate content.

Thanks

Comment: There is no duplicate content. All lines are different

Comment: Should the content be exactly the same, or are you only comparing some columns? Do you want to modify the files in place, or get a unique list only? If a line appears twice, should it appear only once or be completely deleted?

Comment: @gus27 or Unix&Linux (because of `bash`)

Comment: Give a minimal verifiable input and expected output for the question.

Comment: @MYGz: And for `Awk` too!

Comment: `awk -vFS=";" '!unique[$3]++' file`

Comment: awk magic eh? It looks very awfully confusing if you don't know it.

Comment: 1. Do you want all the duplicates, 2. How huge is the directory 3.Would there be anything other than ';' as delimiter

Comment: You need to define what conditions makes for you a line to  be considered as duplicate line. As has been said, all lines seem different. You need to compare IPs? MAC? Names? A combination of those fields?

Comment: A line has duplicate content, when it contains a data (ip, mac, hostname) in any of its parts (column) containing the same as in another line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your comments about what you consider as duplicate this should be close:

```
$ a=$(cut -d';' -f1 c.txt |sort |uniq -d)
$ b=$(cut -d';' -f2 c.txt |sort |uniq -d)
$ c=$(cut -d';' -f3 c.txt |sort |uniq -d)
$ echo "$a:$b:$c"
192.168.1.21:08:00:00:00:00:01:android
```

But in reality we talk about three different situations.
Variable a contains only the duplicate IP , ignoring rest fields.
Variable b contains only the duplicate MAC, ignoring rest fields.
Variable c contains only the duplicate Host Name , ignoring rest fields.

I don't see the meaning on this confusing information.

The only explanation is that you can use a grep later like this:

```
$ grep -v -e "$a" -e "$b" -e "$c" c.txt
192.168.1.22;08:00:00:00:00:03;julia;222222
```

To get the lines from your original file that have a completely unique IP that has not been used even once, a completely unique MAC and a completely unique Host name.

Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. I think that with that "grep" is enough, for what I want.

Comment: You can invert columns with cut: `grep -v -e "$a" -e "$b" -e "$c" c.txt |cut -d';' -f 2,1,3,4`. To match multiple files replace c.txt with `*.txt` or `*` or `/directory/*`

Comment: doesn't work. for example: grep -v -e "$a" | cut -d';' -f 2,3,4  (format a;08:00:00:00:00:03;192.168.1.22;julia;222222 columns interested: mac;ip;host is 2,3,4) and variable is a=$(cut -d';' -f 2,3,4 /directory/* |sort |uniq -d). How can I do it in a single command line without using variables?

Comment: `grep -v -e "$a" | cut -d';' -f 2,3,4` will not work , because you need to provide a file (or a directory) to grep , after `"$a"`. I am a bit confused on what exactly does not work... Maybe is better to post a new question to describe your (new) problem. PS: Use back ticks in comments to format inline code.

Comment: I found similar solution: awk -F\; '{print $2}' * | sort | uniq -d (the same with $3 and $4) Thanks anyway.

Comment: `awk -F\; '{print $2}' * | sort | uniq -d` == `cut -d";" -f2 * |sort |uniq -d`

Comment: `cut -d";" -f2,3,4 * |sort |uniq -d` == `awk -F\; '{print $2,$3,$4}' * | sort | uniq -d`

Comment: the first line error: uniq: incorrect option -- «F» the last line error: uniq: operating extra «;»

Comment: @bdc You are doing something wrong.uniq -d is a valid option in my system. Use man uniq to see manual.